# How to save specific column from sql result into a JSON array?

Tags: php, json

I am executing an SQL query, and I get number of rows as a result:

```
$sql = "SELECT id, name, age FROM users";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

But for certain purpose, I need to save only the id column as a JSON array (containing all the ids of the result), so that in the end I should have a `$idJsonArray` variable that will contain all the ids in this form: `{11, 15, 74, 100}` for example (assuming that the query returned 4 rows containing the ids 11, 15, 74 and 100)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_column()` to extract the `id` column and then `json_encode()` just the result...

```
$jsonIDs = json_encode(array_column($result, "id"));
```

will give...

```
[11, 15, 74, 100]
```

(As it is an array, it will be in `[]` instead of `{}`)

If you need it as an object output, then add `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT` to the encode...

```
$jsonIDs = json_encode(array_column($result, "id"), JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```